# How about blog for Hinduism?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Now am aware that we are still running on private beta but I would like to start a blog so that we can explain some of the posts in brief which may be *too broad* for this website.

For example, we can write some of the briefs like

- About Hinduism
- History
- Origin
- Information on Gods (Kinda Almanac)

and some of the similar topics, I would like some of the professionals to join atleast not in the development part but as far as sharing of the knowledge goes.

That blog will also help us to promote http://hinduism.stackexchange.com on later stage. We will be integrating live feeds from this website as well.

Also, publically, it will be helpful as a resource for Hinduism.

This is just an idea of mine, I would like to hear good/bad comments, everything is welcome.

If you would like to join, please state your area of expertise, time you can dedicate so that we can create a good team and run a blog together.

Comment: Are you talking about a blog at blogoverflow? I mean, the official site for stackexchange blogs?

Comment: @AwalGarg no, the personal ones, so like a community we can run and promote the main

Comment: How do you think would you _promote the blog_, then?

Comment: @AwalGarg we often quote from sources, also I stated that we can write the articles in brief and maintain an almanac, link the blog in answers, as a reference, share the blog posts on twitter, fb etc, there are many ways to do so

Comment: If any mod sees us firing links of a non-official blog in answers for promotion, he will fire us all :P

Comment: @AwalGarg I think it is legal to do so, if we are associating the blog with this particular site only...

Comment: Why not a blogoverflow blog? The official one?

Comment: @AwalGarg I didn't knew we had one :D ya so why not that...

Comment: Yes, we can have that. You need to discuss that in the blogoverflow chat room. _(I can't do that cus a mod suspended me from chatting because I called her a mod :P silly mods!)_...

Comment: We should not start a Blog Overflow blog yet. The site is not mature enough for that.

Comment: I think official blog is for mature site....but doesn't know it in detail.

Comment: @senshin Thats why I wrote *Now am aware that we are still running on private beta*, but again, if we are that mature, we won't need a blog to promote..